# How to add to Qt books example something like add item to list possibility?

Tags: c++, qt, list

So there is a great example that comes with Qt. it is in Examples Books Demonstration. I am new to c++ and even more new to Qt so I wonder what shall be done to add such functionality? I mean what code changes shall be made to it to add 2 buttons like new and submit and what functions they shall trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to read a [Qt tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.0/examples.html#qt-tutorial) (and maybe a C++ tutorial depending on your knowledge of C++).

Have a look at this SO question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475345/

Doing the tutorial, you'll learn how to add buttons to a form and how a function will be triggered when a button is clicked.

I also recommend reading [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160).